# Optus sport error 2006

Tags: 22.04

I keep getting error 2006 when trying to watch content on Optus Sport. I can log in ok and can watch on Windows. How to watch on Ubuntu? many thanks Terry

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same issue on Firefox after installing Ubuntu. I then had a pop up "enable DRM" appear on Firefox browser after refreshing the page. After enabling that it worked.